# router.url does not change it's content when page is changed

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular7, angular8

I want to retrieve the current url of my angular app and perform some tasks. I want the variable containing the url to change when I change the page.

I have written:

```
export class SidenavComponent implements OnInit {

  public href: string = "";
}

ngOnInit() {
     this.href = this.router.url;
    console.log(this.href);
  }
```

The problem is `this.href` is not changing it's content. Suppose I am on the home page, then `this.href` is `"dashboard/home"`.  Now I click on a button and go to a different page, then the url becomes `"localhost:4200/dashboard/target"` but the `this.href` value does not change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Listen to router events to update it.

```
this.router.events.subscribe(() => this.href = this.router.url);
```

Comment: I wrote `this.router.events.subscribe(() => this.href = this.router.url);
      console.log(this.href);` but console is showing nothing. Could you help me?

Comment: this.router.events.subscribe( () => { this.href = this.router.url;  console.log(this.href); });

Comment: @SwapnilSourabh consider learning Angular before using it. Otherwise Dince12 have answered you.

Comment: Thanks both of you. I am new to Angular, sorry for that.